# ошибка майнера в python

Tags: python, json, blockchain

я пишу свой блокчейн. При запуске майнера у меня возникает такая вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Тим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Тим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Тим\PycharmProjects\ksedi coin\ksedi-coin-code\miner.py", line 101, in mine
    NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS = json.loads(NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS)
  File "C:\Users\Тим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Тим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Тим\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

ссылка на репозиторий: https://github.com/timeriny/Ksedi-Coin-code

код майнера:

```
import time
import hashlib
import json
import requests
import base64
from flask import Flask, request
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import ecdsa

from miner_config import MINER_ADDRESS, MINER_NODE_URL, PEER_NODES

node = Flask(__name__)


class Block:
    def __init__(self, index, timestamp, data, previous_hash):
        """Returns a new Block object. Each block is "chained" to its previous
        by calling its unique hash.
        Args:
            index (int): Block number.
            timestamp (int): Block creation timestamp.
            data (str): Data to be sent.
            previous_hash(str): String representing previous block unique hash.
        Attrib:
            index (int): Block number.
            timestamp (int): Block creation timestamp.
            data (str): Data to be sent.
            previous_hash(str): String representing previous block unique hash.
            hash(str): Current block unique hash.
        """
        self.index = index
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.data = data
        self.previous_hash = previous_hash
        self.hash = self.hash_block()

    def hash_block(self):
        """Creates the unique hash for the block. It uses sha256."""
        sha = hashlib.sha256()
        sha.update((str(self.index) + str(self.timestamp) + str(self.data) + str(self.previous_hash)).encode('utf-8'))
        return sha.hexdigest()


def create_genesis_block():
    return Block(0, time.time(), {
        "proof-of-work": 9,
        "transactions": None},
        "0")


# Node's blockchain copy
BLOCKCHAIN = [create_genesis_block()]

NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS = []


def proof_of_work(last_proof, blockchain):
    # Creates a variable that we will use to find our next proof of work
    incrementer = last_proof + 1
    # Keep incrementing the incrementer until it's equal to a number divisible by 7919
    # and the proof of work of the previous block in the chain
    start_time = time.time()
    while not (incrementer % 7919 == 0 and incrementer % last_proof == 0):
        incrementer += 1
        # Check if any node found the solution every 60 seconds
        if int((time.time()-start_time) % 60) == 0:
            # If any other node got the proof, stop searching
            new_blockchain = consensus(blockchain)
            if new_blockchain:
                # (False: another node got proof first, new blockchain)
                return False, new_blockchain
    # Once that number is found, we can return it as a proof of our work
    return incrementer, blockchain


def mine(a, blockchain, node_pending_transactions):
    BLOCKCHAIN = blockchain
    NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS = node_pending_transactions
    while True:
        """Mining is the only way that new coins can be created.
        In order to prevent too many coins to be created, the process
        is slowed down by a proof of work algorithm.
        """
        # Get the last proof of work
        last_block = BLOCKCHAIN[-1]
        last_proof = last_block.data['proof-of-work']
        # Find the proof of work for the current block being mined
        # Note: The program will hang here until a new proof of work is found
        proof = proof_of_work(last_proof, BLOCKCHAIN)
        # If we didn't guess the proof, start mining again
        if not proof[0]:
            # Update blockchain and save it to file
            BLOCKCHAIN = proof[1]
            a.send(BLOCKCHAIN)
            continue
        else:
            # Once we find a valid proof of work, we know we can mine a block so
            # ...we reward the miner by adding a transaction
            # First we load all pending transactions sent to the node server
            NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS = requests.get(url = MINER_NODE_URL + '/txion', params = {'update':MINER_ADDRESS}).content
            NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS = json.loads(NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS)
            # Then we add the mining reward
            NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS.append({
                "from": "network",
                "to": MINER_ADDRESS,
                "amount": 1})
            # Now we can gather the data needed to create the new block
            new_block_data = {
                "proof-of-work": proof[0],
                "transactions": list(NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS)
            }
            new_block_index = last_block.index + 1
            new_block_timestamp = time.time()
            last_block_hash = last_block.hash
            # Empty transaction list
            NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS = []
            # Now create the new block
            mined_block = Block(new_block_index, new_block_timestamp, new_block_data, last_block_hash)
            BLOCKCHAIN.append(mined_block)
            # Let the client know this node mined a block
            print(json.dumps({
              "index": new_block_index,
              "timestamp": str(new_block_timestamp),
              "data": new_block_data,
              "hash": last_block_hash
            }, sort_keys=True) + "\n")
            a.send(BLOCKCHAIN)
            requests.get(url = MINER_NODE_URL + '/blocks', params = {'update':MINER_ADDRESS})

def find_new_chains():
    # Get the blockchains of every other node
    other_chains = []
    for node_url in PEER_NODES:
        # Get their chains using a GET request
        block = requests.get(url = node_url + "/blocks").content
        # Convert the JSON object to a Python dictionary
        block = json.loads(block)
        # Verify other node block is correct
        validated = validate_blockchain(block)
        if validated:
            # Add it to our list
            other_chains.append(block)
    return other_chains


def consensus(blockchain):
    # Get the blocks from other nodes
    other_chains = find_new_chains()
    # If our chain isn't longest, then we store the longest chain
    BLOCKCHAIN = blockchain
    longest_chain = BLOCKCHAIN
    for chain in other_chains:
        if len(longest_chain) < len(chain):
            longest_chain = chain
    # If the longest chain wasn't ours, then we set our chain to the longest
    if longest_chain == BLOCKCHAIN:
        # Keep searching for proof
        return False
    else:
        # Give up searching proof, update chain and start over again
        BLOCKCHAIN = longest_chain
        return BLOCKCHAIN


def validate_blockchain(block):
    """Validate the submitted chain. If hashes are not correct, return false
    block(str): json
    """
    return True


@node.route('/blocks', methods=['GET'])
def get_blocks():
    # Load current blockchain. Only you should update your blockchain
    if request.args.get("update") == MINER_ADDRESS:
        global BLOCKCHAIN
        BLOCKCHAIN = pipe_input.recv()
    chain_to_send = BLOCKCHAIN
    # Converts our blocks into dictionaries so we can send them as json objects later
    chain_to_send_json = []
    for block in chain_to_send:
        block = {
            "index": str(block.index),
            "timestamp": str(block.timestamp),
            "data": str(block.data),
            "hash": block.hash
        }
        chain_to_send_json.append(block)

    # Send our chain to whomever requested it
    chain_to_send = json.dumps(chain_to_send_json, sort_keys=True)
    return chain_to_send


@node.route('/txion', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def transaction():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # On each new POST request, we extract the transaction data
        new_txion = request.get_json()
        # Then we add the transaction to our list
        if validate_signature(new_txion['from'], new_txion['signature'], new_txion['message']):
            NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS.append(new_txion)
            # Because the transaction was successfully
            # submitted, we log it to our console
            print("New transaction")
            print("FROM: {0}".format(new_txion['from']))
            print("TO: {0}".format(new_txion['to']))
            print("AMOUNT: {0}\n".format(new_txion['amount']))
            # Then we let the client know it worked out
            return "Transaction submission successful\n"
        else:
            return "Transaction submission failed. Wrong signature\n"
    # Send pending transactions to the mining process
    elif request.method == 'GET' and request.args.get("update") == MINER_ADDRESS:
        pending = json.dumps(NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS, sort_keys=True)
        # Empty transaction list
        NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS[:] = []
        return pending


def validate_signature(public_key, signature, message):

    public_key = (base64.b64decode(public_key)).hex()
    signature = base64.b64decode(signature)
    vk = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(public_key), curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1)
    # Try changing into an if/else statement as except is too broad.
    try:
        return vk.verify(signature, message.encode())
    except:
        return False


def welcome_msg():
    print("""       =========================================\n
        KSEDI COIN v0.1 - BLOCKCHAIN SYSTEM\n
       =========================================\n\n
        KSEDI OFFICIAL PC MINER\n
        Make sure you are using the latest version!\n\n\n""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    welcome_msg()
    # Start mining
    pipe_output, pipe_input = Pipe()
    miner_process = Process(target=mine, args=(pipe_output, BLOCKCHAIN, NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS))
    miner_process.start()

    # Start server to receive transactions
    transactions_process = Process(target=node.run(), args=pipe_input)
    transactions_process.start()
```

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас `None` в `NODE_PENDING_TRANSACTIONS`. В общем, разбирайтесь с ответом сервера. И проще вместо `.content` сразу брать `.json()`, кстати. Если он там есть.